# Spring Integration JMS with JTA rollback although exception is handled in ErrorHandler

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-transactions, atomikos

I am using Spring Integration with JTA support through Atomikos and JMS bound to different Webshpere MQ and a Oracle Database.
 
Obviosly for others it seems to be the same thread as in [Spring Integration JMS with JTA rollback when message goes to errorChannel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40302776/spring-integration-jms-with-jta-rollback-when-message-goes-to-errorchannel) but it isn't not at all.
The flow is the following:

- message-driven-channel-adapter receive the message within transaction
- some transformations
- ServiceActivator with deeper business logic
- DataBase Update

Everything works really fine expect for one szenario:
If an unchecked exception occurs (maybe due to inkonsistent data which shouldn't be) within the ServiceActivator the message is rethrown and handled within an ErrorHandler (via ErrorChannel).
There - in some cases - the orgininal incoming message should be send to a DeadLetter Queue (Webshere MQ). This is done with outbound-channel-adapter.

See enclosed configuration:

```
       <jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="midxMessageDrivenAdapter"
                                            channel="midxReplyChannel"
                                            acknowledge="auto"
                                            transaction-manager="transactionManager"
                                            connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                                            concurrent-consumers="1"
                                            error-channel="errorChannel"
                                            max-concurrent-consumers="${cmab.integration.midx.max.consumer}"
                                            idle-task-execution-limit="${cmab.integration.midx.idleTaskExecutionLimit}"
                                            receive-timeout="${cmab.integration.midx.receiveTimeout}"
                                            destination="midxReplyQueue"/>
................
<int:service-activator input-channel="midxReplyProcessChannel" ref="processMidxReplyDbWriter" />

        <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel" ref="inputErrorHandler" />

        <jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="deadLetterOutboundChannelAdapter"
                                      channel="errorDlChannel" destination="deadLetterQueue"
                                      delivery-persistent="true" connection-factory="nonXAConnectionFactory"/>
```

**Some important hints:**

message-driven-channel-adapter:

- connectionFactory is a MQXAQueueConnectionFactory wihtin an AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean
- transaction-manager is Spring JtaTransactionManager

outbound-channel-adapter:
connection-factory is a nonXAConnectionFactory.

```
CachingConnectionFactory cachingConnectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
.....
cachingConnectionFactory.setTargetConnectionFactory(mqQueueConnectionFactory);
return cachingConnectionFactory;
```

**And now the error which I observed:**
Although I handled the unchecked exception in my ErrorHandler (ref="inputErrorHandler"; send the message to DeadLetter-Queue) an rollback is initiated and the message-driven-channel-adapter receives the message again and again.
Curious is the fact that indeed the message is delivered to the DeadLetterQueue via the outbound-channel-adapter. The destination (deadLetterQueue) contains the failed messages.

Question: What I'm doing wrong? The failed original incoming message is rolled back although I handled the exception in my ErrorHandler.
Any help really appreciate. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Show, please, what your `inputErrorHandler` does

Comment: My ErrorInputHandler is a ServiceActivator. It recognize if the incmoing throwable is instanceof MessageTransformationException or MessageHandlingException. In my case (see above) it is a MessageHandlingException. 
I have to put the code in a new answer because there are too many characters for a comment.

Comment: Do you rethrow exception from your `ErrorInputHandler` ?

Comment: Definitively no.
See my "answer". I couldn't placed all the information within an comment.

Answer (score 0):

concerning to my comment see enclose code of my InputErrorHandler:

```
if (throwable instanceof MessageHandlingException) {

            MessageHandlingException messageHandlingException = (MessageHandlingException) throwable;

            if (messageHandlingException.getCause() != null
                    && (messageHandlingException.getCause() instanceof CmabProcessDbException
                    || messageHandlingException.getCause() instanceof CmabReplyFormatException)) {

                String appMessage = ((CmabException) messageHandlingException.getCause()).getAppMessagesAsString();

                LOGGER.error(String.format("cmab rollback exception occured: %s", appMessage));
                LOGGER.error("******** initiate rollback *********");

                throw throwable.getCause();

            } else {

                ErrorDto payload = fillMessagePayload(messageHandlingException, throwableClassName);
                sendMessageToTargetQueue(payload);
            }
```

As I mentioned the "business" ServiceActivator throws an unchecked exception so in this case the ELSE-Statements are calling.
Within that I build up a Message with MessagBuilder and sends it ti the errorDlChannel (s. above the outbound-channel-adapter!).

```
 private void sendMessageToDeadLetterQueue(Message<?> message, String description, String cause) {

.......

        Message<?> mb =
                MessageBuilder.withPayload(message.getPayload())
                        .copyHeaders(message.getHeaders())
                        .setHeaderIfAbsent("senderObject", this.getClass().getName())
                        .setHeaderIfAbsent("errorText", description)
                        .setHeaderIfAbsent("errorCause", errorCause).build();

        errorDlChannel.send(mb);

    }
```

That's all. This is for this case the last statement. There is nothing anything else in the main method of my ErrorHandler. No rethrow or other stuff.
So this is the reason of my confusion. For me the exception is handled by sending it to the errorDlChannel (outbound-channel-adapter -> DeadLetterQueue).
I saw the message on the DeadLetter Queue but nevertheless a jta rollback occurs...and IMO this shouldn't bee.

Comment: OK. I got it. There is `AbstractTransactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()`. Would be great if you are able to place there breakpoint and investigate who and how does that for us.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get it at all. Should I check the transaction status with my ErrorHandler? I currently don't know what you adivce.

Comment: M-m-m. No. You should *debug* the application with the breakpoint in the mentioned class. Or... You can share with me some simple Spring Boot app and I'll do that for you.

Comment: My code is well tested .... also with integration test. Well, no problem.
I set a breakpoint in the AbstractTransactionStatus, method <public void setRollbackOnly()> and run my integration test.
The test sends a message to the queue where the message-driven-channel-adapter is looking at. In the Business-ServiceActivitor an unchecked exception occurs and the ErrorHandler is called. The message is send to DeadLetter-Queue. Surely, all with ActiveMQXAConnectionFactory :-)  BUT transactional with Atomikos! All the same stuff!  Nevertheless the code does not stop at the breakpoint you mentioned?!

Comment: Need to debug further to determine where and why your TX is rolled back...

Comment: But at the end of the integrations test the following message appears:

2017-08-04 16:45:27,489 WARN   DefaultMessageListenerContainer handleListenerSetupFailure 871 - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'queue://midx.reply.test.queue' - trying to recover. Cause: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction set to rollback only
The midx.reply.test.queue is an ActiveMQ-Queue an the input test queue for message-driven-channel-adapter.

Comment: The `DefaultMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerSetupFailure()` is definitely called from the `catch (Throwable ex) {` block of the `AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run()`. So, that looks like something has thrown exception anyway... You can continue debug from that point though

Comment: M-m-m. Maybe your integration test has something like `@Rollback` ?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. In debug modus I observed that the handleListenerSetupFailure method is called AFTER my ErrorHandler-ServiceActivator....? Is this the normal behaviour? And the alreadyRecovered-Flag hasn't been set.

Comment: I don't know. Need to understand who throws exception after your `ErrorHandler`

Comment: No, my integration test acts like PROD and hasn't any rollback annotation.
I remarked after sending the message to the error channel that within the spring stack a new transaction is created...
Don't know why. I will have a closer look at the mechanism.

Comment: You have a new TX there because you use different `ConnecitonFactory` for sending to DLQ. Would be great to have simple Boot app to investigate. Hard to reproduce...